# ImportError: cannot import name 'SchemaInferenceError' from 'datasets.arrow_writer' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_writer.py)

Tags: python, large-language-model

I need the following libraries for fine-tunning an LLM using QLora. The problem comes from library version specifically should be `datasets` and `trl`. I couldn't find the online discussion that resolved this issue.

```bash
!pip install -q bitsandbytes transformers peft accelerate datasets==2.16.0 scipy einops evaluate trl pyarrow==11.0.0
```

```py
import os
# disable Weights and Biases
os.environ['WANDB_DISABLED']="true"
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    HfArgumentParser,
    AutoTokenizer,
    TrainingArguments,
    Trainer,
    GenerationConfig
)
from tqdm import tqdm
from trl import SFTTrainer
import torch
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from huggingface_hub import interpreter_login

interpreter_login()
```

Error:

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 13
      2 from transformers import (
      3     AutoModelForCausalLM,
      4     AutoTokenizer,
   (...)
     10     GenerationConfig
     11 )
     12 from tqdm import tqdm
---> 13 from trl import SFTTrainer
     14 import torch
     15 import time

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trl/__init__.py:23
      8 from .import_utils import (
      9     is_bitsandbytes_available,
     10     is_diffusers_available,
   (...)
     14     is_xpu_available,
     15 )
     16 from .models import (
     17     AutoModelForCausalLMWithValueHead,
     18     AutoModelForSeq2SeqLMWithValueHead,
   (...)
     21     setup_chat_format,
     22 )
---> 23 from .trainer import (
     24     DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM,
     25     DPOTrainer,
     26     IterativeSFTTrainer,
     27     ModelConfig,
     28     PPOConfig,
     29     PPOTrainer,
     30     RewardConfig,
     31     RewardTrainer,
     32     SFTTrainer,
     33 )
     34 from .trainer.utils import get_kbit_device_map, get_peft_config, get_quantization_config
     37 if is_diffusers_available():

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trl/trainer/__init__.py:46
     44 from .reward_config import RewardConfig
     45 from .reward_trainer import RewardTrainer, compute_accuracy
---> 46 from .sft_trainer import SFTTrainer

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trl/trainer/sft_trainer.py:24
     22 from accelerate.state import PartialState
     23 from datasets import Dataset
---> 24 from datasets.arrow_writer import SchemaInferenceError
     25 from datasets.builder import DatasetGenerationError
     26 from transformers import (
     27     AutoModelForCausalLM,
     28     AutoTokenizer,
   (...)
     34     TrainingArguments,
     35 )

ImportError: cannot import name 'SchemaInferenceError' from 'datasets.arrow_writer' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datasets/arrow_writer.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update datasets library.

I had the same error. After updating to datasets ( 2.18.0 ) , I can run

```
from datasets.arrow_writer import SchemaInferenceError
```

without this error.

To update:

```
pip install -U datasets
```